# PXE boot server on a xen PV guest?

Tags: ubuntu, xen, pxe-boot, paravirtualization

I've set up a Xen hypervisor on ubuntu 14.04 and a PV guest also on ubuntu 14.04.
I want this PV guest to be a PXE boot server. But when I look at the `/boot` folder I see that it's empty.

I'm a newbie in virtualization. So where am I supposed to:

1. take a kernel?
2. run `mkinitramfs` to prepare initrd for a network boot?

**UPDATE**
Dear colleagues. I actually need an advice on the workflow of **making a custom initrd.img** on a PV guest. I know all the stuff regarding setting up a PXE boot server on a host machine. I just want to understand where can I take a kernel image on a PV guest AND what happens to a PV guest when the kernel is updated via apt-get.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It PVGRUB. This tutorial covers all my questions http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/PvGrub

Comment: It would have been nice if you'd made it clear that you only want to boot VM's this way.  Otherwise jfried's answer is closer to what you'd want to do.

Comment: @Matt on the opposite. I'm going to boot only hardware diskless servers with the help of this boot server. What jfried wrote is good but it is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boot systems via network you need 3 things:

- a dhcp server (for example isc dhcp)
- a tftp server
- a location where you can download the preseeding file

**DHCP**

The DHCP server has to offer the IP and the boot server to the client.

An example configuration for isc dhcp looks like this:

```
subnet 10.1.20.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 {
   option routers 10.1.20.1;

   next-server 10.1.22.150;
   filename "/pxelinux.0";

   on commit {
        set clip = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
        set clhw = binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6));
        execute("/srv/rexio/middleware/bin/rex_io_pxe_dhcpevent", "commit", clip, clhw);
   }
}
```

The "next-server" directive tells the client where it finds the tftp server.
As you see in the example you can also define a script that gets triggert when a client requests an ip.
In this example it calls a script that dynamically creates the pxe boot command file.

**TFTP**

For this you can use hpa tftpd. You have to place the kernel and initrd (and the pxe boot command file) in the tftp folder.

You can find the files you need for this (for ubuntu 14.04, 64bit) here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

Just download these files and place them in the tftp root folder (i think on ubuntu it is /var/lib/tftpboot).

**the preseeding file**

To really automate your installation you need a preseeding file. An example for ubuntu can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt (this is for 10.04, but i think it won't change much for 14.04)

You can place this file on a http webserver and point the installation to it (via a kernel parameter)

```
preseed/url=http://ip.of.your.server/preseed.cfg
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But this is not what I need. I actually know all this stuff. Please, see the update on the topic.